# Difference between Azure Container Instances and Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure

Microsoft announced [Azure Container Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-apps/), a new service  for
running serverless containers in the cloud. This appears to be similar to the [Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/#overview) service, which is also for deploying fully-managed containers.

What are the key differences between these two services?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's a good question and I've asked the team about it because it wasn't clear to me either.

In summary: if you'll spin up multiple container (e.g. front end / backend / database), Azure Container Apps is a better choice as it comes with Dapr and it will auto retry the requests and add some telemetry data.

If you just need long running jobs or you don't need multiple containers to communicate with each other, you can go with Azure Container Instances.

**Azure Container Instances**

> Azure Container Instances (ACI) provides a single pod of Hyper-V
> isolated containers on demand. It can be thought of as a lower-level
> "building block" option compared to Container Apps. Concepts like
> scale, load balancing, and certificates are not provided with ACI
> containers. For example, to scale to five container instances, you
> create five distinct container instances. Azure Container Apps provide
> many application-specific concepts on top of containers, including
> certificates, revisions, scale, and environments. Users often interact
> with Azure Container Instances through other services. For example,
> Azure Kubernetes Service can layer orchestration and scale on top of
> ACI through virtual nodes. If you need a less "opinionated" building
> block that doesn't align with the scenarios Azure Container Apps is
> optimizing for, Azure Container Instances is an ideal option.

**Azure Container Apps**

> Azure Container Apps enables you to build serverless microservices
> based on containers. Distinctive features of Container Apps include:
>
> Optimized for running general purpose containers, especially for
> applications that span many microservices deployed in containers.
> Powered by Kubernetes and open-source technologies like Dapr, KEDA,
> and envoy. Supports Kubernetes-style apps and microservices with
> features like service discovery and traffic splitting. Enables
> event-driven application architectures by supporting scale based on
> traffic and pulling from event sources like queues, including scale to
> zero. Support of long running processes and can run background tasks.
> Azure Container Apps doesn't provide direct access to the underlying
> Kubernetes APIs. If you require access to the Kubernetes APIs and
> control plane, you should use Azure Kubernetes Service. However, if
> you would like to build Kubernetes-style applications and don't
> require direct access to all the native Kubernetes APIs and cluster
> management, Container Apps provides a fully managed experience based
> on best-practices. For these reasons, many teams may prefer to start
> building container microservices with Azure Container Apps.

source:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/compare-options

Comment: Note that you can use ACA without using Dapr and that ACI can run single and multiple containers apps.

Comment: another thing: Azure Container Apps can also scale to 0 containers (thanks to KEDA).

Answer (score 7):

In a nutshell, workloads on ACI are usually started and stopped by some kind of process or trigger and are usually short-lived while workloads on ACA are usually long-running processes like a Web app.

Comment: What about AppService? isn't that also for constantly running processes?

Comment: It is, but there are more things you can do in a container than they allow via AppService.  This video discusses some scenarios: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe_AYBD5m0I